# How to distinguish "upload" and "download" function in JetBrains sync settings?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

There is only one button for IDEA sync setting, how could IDEA know I want to upload my settings or download my settings from a remote setting server?

For example, I have a plugin list, and there are 3 plugins: A, B, C. I delete plugin A for some reason, so when I click the button "sync settings" what will happen? Download plugin A or remove A in that remote setting server? Because I may want to delete plugin A or I want plugin A back.

Comment: Please check related part in documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#f072817d

Comment: I have read the IDE settings documentation, but still can't solve my problem

Comment: After selecting "Sync Settings to JetBrains Account" you'll get dialog with "Get Settings from Account" and "Keep and Sync Local settings"  options.So you may choose.

Comment: I tried this on another PC and I figure it out, thanks a lot!